# how to resolve Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error while using import-excel

Tags: powershell

i have installed excel module and powershell version is 5.0 
trying to use this in a Windows server 2012.

complete error message

PS C:\Users\sumanth> import-excel
import-excel : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Have you had a look at Get-Help

Comment: Please add the command you executed too.

Comment: just import-excel would throw this message in server.  same thing is working fine in my VDI and laptop. not sure what am i missing in server. 
PS C:\Users\sumanth> import-excel
import-excel : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException

Comment: result when i run the same command in laptop                                                                         PS C:\Users\sumanth> import-excel

cmdlet Import-Excel at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path: